# 任意のジェネリクスを受け取る配列の型の付け方

Tags: typescript

ひとつの配列の中に複数のジェネリクスを持つ配列型を定義したいです。

達成したいことは下記コードのようなケースです。

```js
type BlockType = "hasNumber" | "hasBoolean";

type NumberAttribute = {
  numberProp: number;
}

type BooleanAttribute = {
  booleanProp: boolean;
}

type Attribute<T extends BlockType> =
  T extends "hasNumber" ? NumberAttribute :
  T extends "hasBoolean" ? BooleanAttribute :
  never;

type Block<T extends BlockType> = {
  id: string;
  type: T;
  attribute: Attribute<T>;
}

type BlockList = Block<"hasNumber" | "hasBoolean">[];

const list: BlockList = [
  {
    id: "id001",
    type: "hasNumber", // type が決まれば
    attribute: { numberProp: 0 }, // attribute も決まる
  },
  {
    id: "id002",
    type: "hasBoolean", // 同一配列内に異なる type を含むことができる
    attribute: { booleanProp: false },
  },
  {
    id: "id003",
    type: "hasNumber", // type === "hasNumber" のときは
    attribute: { booleanProp: false }, // attibute.booleanProp をコンパイルエラーにしたい(現状はエラーにならない)
  },
]
```

`BlockType` はあとから増える可能性があり、その `BlockType` によって `Attribute` の型が変わります。
`Block`は `id`, `type`, `attribute` を持つことは変わりません。

ソースコード上のコメントにもある通り、 `type` の値によって `attribute` の型が確定できるようにしたいです。

`type BlockList = Block<"hasNumber" | "hasBoolean">[];` のような指定では目的の仕様は達成できませんでした。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Block`と`BlockList`を次のように書き換えれば目的の仕様になります。

```
type SingleTypeBlock<T extends BlockType> = {
  id: string;
  type: T;
  attribute: Attribute<T>;
}
type GetBlock<T extends BlockType> = T extends BlockType ? SingleTypeBlock<T> : never;

type Block = GetBlock<BlockType>;

type BlockList = Block[];
```

質問者さんがお書きになった`Block<T>`型は`SingleTypeBlock<T>`と改名しました。
実は、今回欲しいのは`SingleTypeBlock<"hasNumber"> | SingleTypeBlock<"hasBoolean">`というユニオン型です。この定義にすれば、`list`の3つ目のようなちぐはぐな値を弾くことができます。
しかし、手動で`SingleTypeBlock<"hasNumber"> | SingleTypeBlock<"hasBoolean">`と書くのは`BlockType`があとから増えた際に大変ですから、`BlockType`が増えれば自動的にユニオン型の構成要素が増えるようにしたいです。
それを担うのが`GetBlock<BlockType>`です。これはconditional typeのunion distributionという挙動を利用して、`BlockType`の構成要素の各`T`に対して`SingleTypeBlock<T>`を計算し、それらのユニオン型をとるようになっています。
よって、`GetBlock<BlockType>`が`SingleTypeBlock<"hasNumber"> | SingleTypeBlock<"hasBoolean">`に計算されます。